# How to properly upgrade gcc on Centos 7?

Tags: bash, centos, python, gcc

I did this to upgrade gcc from 4.8.5 to gcc 7:

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-7-gcc*
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable
```

This does give me the gcc 7 in the current bash terminal. However, if I start a python terminal, it displays that the gcc is still gcc 4.8.5, as below:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-7.3.1-20180303/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5) (GCC)
```

And in python terminal:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Feb 24 2020, 16:34:54) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Also, after I log off and log in back to the machine, the default gcc version is still 4.8.5 and I have to execute again:

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable
```

So I have two questions:

1. after gcc 7 is enabled, how to make the python(3) version's gcc 4.8.5 become gcc 7 too?
2. Is there a way to make the gcc 7 default in the whole centos system? And this might solve the problem of 1).

Comment: Update your path. See http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: @DavidPostill how to update the path? I don't know where gcc 7 is installed by commands above.

Comment: The `gcc` version in the python terminal should be the version that compiles python it self, not the effective `gcc` in your current shell.

Answer (score 12):

I've confirmed that you can upgrade gcc from the default version 4.8 on centOS 7.

First, we need to install "Software Collections" in order to access some of the community packages including `gcc v7`

- `sudo yum install -y centos-release-scl`

Next, we want to install a developer toolset. Depending on your needs, you may want a different devtoolset. Here I'm targeting 7:

- `sudo yum install -y devtoolset-7`

Finally, you'll want to change over to `gcc 7` as your default, launch a new shell session with the `scl` tool:

- `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash`

Answer (score 0):

Enable the software collection in the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1758987/771784) is only effective in the current shell.
The `scl` utility will create a sub-shell that set the `PATH` variables properly, so that in the new sub-shell, the enabled software collections will be firstly searched.
These settings obviously only take effective temporarily in the current shell.

To make it permanently effective, add the command, `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable` to the user's profile (`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` for RHEL based OS, like CentOS 7).
Then, start a new shell and you will have the right tools available.

> After execute `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash`, you will need to execute `exit` twice to exit the opened shell window, which verifies that the `scl` command created a sub-shell.
> There might be side-effect with creating a sub-shell, so do not put this in the `~/.bashrc` profile, otherwise it will repeatedly create sub-shell (non-login shell) as each shell will load the profile, resulting in a dead loop.
> Put it in `~/.bash_profile`, it will be loaded for only once (for the login shell), but you will need to exit twice every time.

But for development purpose, `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash` would be preferred, as you can exit the created sub-shell, and then switch to different versions of the same software.

---

More details about the GCC version in python terminal:

> The version info of the built-in Python in CentOS 7:
>
> ```
> [root@conda condabuilder]# python
> Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) 
> [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> ```
>
> The version info of the user installed (via `conda`) Python:
>
> ```
> [root@conda condabuilder]# conda activate jupyter
> (jupyter) [root@conda condabuilder]# python
> Python 3.10.9 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb  2 2023, 20:20:04) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> ```
>
> Hence, the GCC version is not related to the system's GCC.

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to have them set their system GCC version for "this" development operation but have a different operation that was tooled using system GCC version that may experience issues.